# How do you receive GET/POST input with Invision Power Board

Tags: php, invision-power-board

So I’m trying to start learning how to create plug-ins for Invision Power Board but am uncertain how to receive GET/POST user input.

Is it through something like:

```
$this->memberData['member_id']
```

Thanks very much in advance.

Comment: What you mean is get all POST or GET variables and its content?

Comment: @kimbarcelona Well to get a specific post or get request and store it in a variable.

Comment: Hmmm.. can you try print_r($_POST) or print_r($_GET) and see what you can do with that?

Comment: Im kind of more interested in seeing what the standard is for such an operation and whether memberData performs that operation @kimbarcelona

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For IP Board 4** , Use something like this

```
\IPS\Request::i()->member_id
```

Here member_id is input name